# Shouold picture resources be added to our "Resources for Blender" question

Tags: discussion, answers

I think seeing as there is a great deal of overlap between textures and pictures, another category should be added to [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15358/2217). Something where free stock photos sites can be put. Sites such as [morgueFile](http://www.morguefile.com/archive) or [stockvault](http://www.stockvault.net/).

Comment: As in reference images?